# program to delete a file in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16

I am trying to delete a file in assembly language but its shows  *illegal path*

I am using tasm or dosbox

```
.MODEL SMALL

.STACK 100H

.DATA

FNAME       DB      'file.txt' ,0

.CODE

MAIN PROC
 
MOV AX,@DATA

MOV DS,AX                   ;initialize OS

MOV AH, 41H                     ;For deleting file

LEA DX, FNAME               ;DX has filename address

INT 21H                     

MOV AH, 4CH                  ; return control to DOS

INT 21H

   MAIN ENDP

 END MAIN
```

Comment: Your code looks correct.  Is the file present at the desired path (i.e. in the working directory on the current drive)?  Is it being removed?  Note that `AX` only contains an error code if CF is set on exit.

Comment: your code is correct. what do you do to assemble/link the code, where do you get the error message? most probably NOT from your own binary, since DOS will not show any error message there

Answer (score 0):

Use `MOV DX, OFFSET(FNAME)`
This will solve your problem for sure!

Comment: That has exactly the same effect as `LEA DX, FNAME`,  but is 1 byte shorter.  It's an optimization, but the question claims there's some kind of correctness problem, not speed or code-size.  (Comments say the code *is* correct, though, so probably just building it wrong, or running it with a current directory that didn't contain `file.txt`)